# Web app using OAuth2 to authenticate with Microsoft works in debug but not deployed

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I have an ASP.Net app with MVC that needs to access the user's OneDrive once they've logged on via standard OAuth2 calls. It works fine from the localhost:xxxx version but once deployed it fails. The symptom is that it asks for the user to log in and even asks them to okay the list of items on OneDrive that we access (I get an email telling me that I granted access from Microsoft) but it doesn't seem to get the tokens back to the application for storage.

I can see that locally everything is handled via https://login.live.com and my app gets a POST and a GET from there. For the release version on the live server, it seems to be using https://login.microsoftonline.com instead. I added CORS for both of that with allows for GET and POST.

The application just rolls back to the starting state waiting for the user to log in. The code looks pretty stock:

```
        public void SignIn()
        {
            GlobalData.LogFile($"\tIn SignIn top...");

            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                GlobalData.LogFile($"\tIn SignIn not IsAuth...");
                // Signal OWIN to send an authorization request to Azure
                Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
```

and it's!Request.IsAuthenticated never switches as it does in the Debug version.

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be blocking me? This is the last bit to get my